# Do the number of units in a layer need to be defined within a conditional scope when using keras tuner to setup a model?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, keras-tuner

According to the Keras Tuner examples [here](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/examples/helloworld/) and [here](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/#the-search-space-may-contain-conditional-hyperparameters), if you want to define the number of layers and each layer's units in a deep learning model using hyper parameters you do something like this:

```
for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 1, 10)):
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('unit_' + str(i), 32, 512, 32)))
```

However, as others have noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61375125/keras-tuner-mismatch-between-number-of-layers-used-and-number-of-layers-reporte) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/66) after the oracle has seen a model with `num_layers = 10` it will always assign a value to `unit_0` through `unit_9`, even when `num_layers` is less than 10.

In the case that `num_layers = 1` for example, only `unit_0` will be used to build the model. But, `unit_1` through `unit_9` will be defined and ***active*** in the hyper parameters.

Does the oracle "know" that `unit_1` through `unit_9` weren't actually used to build the model (and therefore disregard their relevance for impacting the results of that trial)?

Or, does it assume `unit_1` through `unit_9` are being used because they have been defined (and calling `hp.get('unit_9')` for example will return a value)?

In the latter case **the oracle is using misinformation to drive the tuning process**. As a result **it will take longer to converge** (at best) and **incorrectly converge** to a solution as a result of assigning relevance to the unused hyper parameters (at worst).

Should the model actually be defined using [conditional scopes](https://keras-team.github.io/keras-tuner/documentation/hyperparameters/#conditional_scope-method), like this?

```
num_layers = hp.Int('num_layers', 1, 10)
for i in range(num_layers):
    with hp.conditional_scope('num_layers', list(range(i + 1, 10 + 1))):
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('unit_' + str(i), 32, 512, 32)))
```

When defining the model like this, if `num_layers < 10`, calling `hp.get('unit_9')` will return a `ValueError: Conditional parameter unit_10 is not currently active`, as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using conditional scope is the best as it correctly recognizes active parameters. Without using conditional scope it is, at least at the moment, not possible to let the tuner know what parameters are actually used.

However, when using RandomSearch the simpler way (that allows inactive parameters to be there) the result should be exactly the same. When starting a new trial the tuner will go through all possibilities, but will reject the invalid ones before actually starting the trial.

For the existing tuners I think only Bayesian is strongly affected by this. I am not 100% sure about the case of Hyperband; but for RandomSearch the two approaches are exactly the same (except for displaying inactive parameters that make people confused).

Comment: Make's sense random is not negatively affected. Hyperband allows inactive parameters to exist, but unsure how it strongly it affects the alogrithm's performance. 

TODO (give me a couple days): Use `.search()` for Bayesian/Hyperband with/without conditional scoping then compare run times, ultimate parameter selection, and test set performance.